# Jitter in OpenCV Circle Detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I am working on a project and I need to determine the location of circles in a live feed from a camera.

I have already managed to get this kinda running, but I get a weird jitter with the recognition of the circles, and sometimes a circle is not recognized at all.

Here is a Example of this:

[image]

The function I Use for editing the Image is:

```
    def preprocess_image(self):
        self.image = cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        # apply GuassianBlur to reduce noise. medianBlur is also added for smoothening, reducing noise.
        self.image = cv2.GaussianBlur(self.image,(5,5),0);
        self.image = cv2.medianBlur(self.image,5)
        
        # Adaptive Guassian Threshold is to detect sharp edges in the Image. For more information Google it.
        self.image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(self.image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
                cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,3.5)
        
        kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
        self.image = cv2.erode(self.image,kernel,iterations = 1) # gray = erosion
        self.image = cv2.dilate(self.image,kernel,iterations = 1) # gray = dilation
```

And the Method for detecting the circles is:

```
    def get_circles(self):
        rows = self.image.shape[0] # width of the image (1280)
        # detect circles in the image
        self.circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
            self.image, 
            cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
            1, 
            rows / 8, 
            param1=self.parameters["param1"], 
            param2=self.parameters["param2"], 
            minRadius=self.parameters["minRadius"], 
            maxRadius=self.parameters["maxRadius"]
        )

        if self.circles is None: return None
        self.circles = np.round(self.circles[0, :]).astype("int")
```

How do I get rid of this jitter and the sometimes missing recognition of the circles?

Comment: jitter, not gitter. -- that happens because you use *hough transforms*. don't. hough transforms are a newbie trap. they have their uses, but DO NOT solve most things that newbies think they can apply them to. Hough transforms make those situations *even worse*. it's not like homeopathy or praying (which never hurt). -- also: work with white objects on black background, i.e. invert the picture. then find connected components. then you can fit a circle around (minEnclosingCircle) or through (fitEllipse) for each component (or discard the component if it's too small/large or not circular enough)

Comment: I'd recommend that you additionally present clean input data (a frame or two, nothing drawn on) and code that runs on that, instead of a live feed. [mre].

Comment: Why are you using same duplicated `self.image`?

Comment: If you can obtain candidates of interest position and coarse circle parameter from Hough Transform (as stable as the your result), just use the result as hint, not as your last result.
Employ some post-process to confirm and refine parameter.

Comment: "Missing" will simply solved with more weak threshold value. And, if it cause some false positives, rejecting them is work of your post-process.

Comment: If you are using multiple threading, it could be because you are assigned the `self.circles` in two different lines. You could use an auxiliary variable `circles = cv2.HoughCircles( ...` and at the end `self.circles = circles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by ditching hough transforms and instead using connectedComponentsWithStats to transform the circles into black blobs as suggested by Christoph Rackwitz.

Then I used the SimpleBlobDetector to detect the wanted circles.

This works way better then before!

Here is the Code I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_circles(image):
    _, labels, _, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image)

    # Extract the pixels associated with the current label
    label_mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    label_mask[labels == 1] = 255

    params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

    # Set Area filtering parameters
    params.filterByArea = True
    params.minArea = 1000
    params.maxArea = 10000

    params.filterByCircularity = True
    params.minCircularity = .7

    # Create a detector with the parameters
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

    # Detect blobs
    keypoints = detector.detect(label_mask)
    circles = []
    for kp in keypoints:
        circles.append(np.array([int(kp.pt[0]), int(kp.pt[1]), int(kp.size / 2)]))
    
    return circles

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("<your sample video>")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if np.sum(frame) == 0:[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        break

    detect_circles(frame)

    # draw the circles on image here 

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break   

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

And this is the result:
[image]